# React-Native with laravel-echo and pusher-js

Tags: react-native, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I have a Laravel event that uses laravel-echo and pusher-js and it works perfectly in the VueJS frontend for listening to events.
But when I try to open the connection with react-native, I get the following message on the console:

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> unavailable"]

Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"wss","url":"wss://my-api.company.io:443/app/27e7ea97c76452f70b2e?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
```

This is my configuration in app:

```js
  import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from "pusher-js/react-native";

  async function listenMessages() {
    const access_token = await userLogged.access_token;
    console.log("user id: ", "Bearer " + access_token);
    window.Pusher = Pusher;
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    let PusherClient = new Pusher("27e7ea97c7x1x1x1x1x1", {
      cluster: "mt1",
      wsHost: "my-api.company.io",
      wsPort: "8443",
      enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
      forceTLS: false,
      encrypted: false,
    });

    let echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "pusher",
      client: PusherClient,
    });

    await echo.channel(`user.${chat.user.id}`).listen(".SendMessage", (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}

  useEffect(() => {
    listenMessages();
  });
```

And I don't know if it's in my backend or in the mobile, 'cause this works in another web application.

Comment: Make sure your emulator or phone internet connection available.

Comment: @ridvanaltun You say in code ou in device???

Comment: Device and app, both.